# using a try but still having a exception

Tags: java, exception

Good morning.
I have a method "insert" in a "table" class.
in this method i take the members of the class and i write them on the db with a preparedStatement.
i whould that the "insert" throw a SQLException if the things goes wrong.
this is the source:

```
public void insert() throws SQLException
    {

    PreparedStatement sqlCommand = null;
    try
        {
        sqlCommand = this.db.prepareStatement(prepareInsertQuery());
        sqlCommand.execute();
        }
    finally
        {
        if (sqlCommand!=null)
            {
            sqlCommand.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is a problem:
if i put a "catch SQLException" block,i must handle the exception INSIDE my method, and i don't want it (i want to put exception handling in main program, for logging).
if i don't put a "catch SQLException", the exception will be ignored.

how can i do to close the sqlCommand but if i get a exception, to propagate it?

thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "the exception will be ignored"? If the body of the `try` generates an exception, the entire method will then throw the same exception (unless the `finally` block throws an exception).

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything else.  If an exception is thrown, it already will propagate up to the calling method, since you're not catching it here.

Comment: OP might want to enclose the `sqlCommand.close()` statement in a `try/catch` to prevent an exception in the `close` from hiding an exception thrown in the body of the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

If the body of the `try` generates an exception that is not caught, then the exception is not ignored; rather, the method will terminate with that exception (unless the `finally` clause also generates an exception, in which case the original exception will be lost).

If you are using Java 7 or later, you should be using the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax. This is available because `PreparedStatement` implements `AutoCloseable`:

```
public void insert() throws SQLException
{

    try (PreparedStatement sqlCommand = this.db.prepareStatement(prepareInsertQuery()))
    {
        sqlCommand.execute();
    }
}
```